# как установить значения по умолчанию в __init__() при в наследующих классах?

Tags: python, классы, наследование, default

```
 class cart():
    def __init__(self,number_of_wheels,power,type_of_engines = 'лошадиная сила'):
        self.number_of_wheels = number_of_wheels
        self.power = power
        self.type_of_engines = type_of_engines

class car():
    def __init__(self,year,model,number_of_wheels,power, type_of_engines = 'двигатель внутренего сгоряния'):
        super(car,self).__init__(self,number_of_wheels,power,type_of_engines)
        self.year = year
        self.model = model

cart1 = cart(4,1)
print(cart1.type_of_engines)
car1 = car(1999,'mini',4,40)
print(car1.type_of_engines)
```

Comment: не выводит car1.type_of_engines

Comment: Вы не унаследовали класс `cart`: `class car(cart)`.

Comment: не помагает, то же самое

Comment: уберите `self` из аргументов вызова `__init__`  `super(car,self).__init__(self,number_of_wheels,power,type_of_engines)`